# Eclipse CVS Commit, ignore certain file types

Tags: eclipse, cvs, commit

I have a rather large project made up of lots of...projects, each with their own Debug and Release folders along with a bunch of other files that I don't really want to commit like .rc and .user.

At the moment I right click the top folder, click commit and eclipse asks how i would like to store all these "new files" it has detected, how do i tell it I don't want to commit any of them.

So far i have read that i need a .cvsignore file but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried doing a "clean" of the project but there was still plenty of files i don't want.

Does anyone have any advice on how to make this at the very least less painful? I have even tried doing a search on the project for certain . files I don't want and deleting them but some of them re-create themselves....

Note: I usually just commit the files I want by selecting them individually but this time it is about 600+ files...

***UPDATE***

Sorry for taking so long. Thank you to everyone for their answers, they are all technically correct, none actually worked for me, but i will mark Burhan as the best answer

I have tried the cvs ignore route before and it never seemed to work, unfortunately it still didn't work for me.

The per directory approach does seem to work but its quite a painful process in this case. But khmarbaise is correct this is the documented method, and is actually correct.

The Global method Burhan mentioned seemed ideal but didn't seem to work, Perhaps i have mis-understood where CVSROOT is, i always assumed it was the "CVS" folder located in the top most directory, it includes files like "Tag", "Root" etc. is this wrong?

@thkala, the "Team->Add to .cvsignore" was always greyed out for me and therefore could not be used but again is another valid route when it does work.

However I think i have finally realized why I have so many problems with CVS and eclipse and i would like to post what finally worked for me and what may actually be the missing link for the .cvsignore route.

I always checked the project out this way: **CVS Repositoris -> Right click the branch -> check out as -> check out as project in the workspace.**

However the reason i was having so many problems with **cvs and indexing** what i should have done is:
**CVS Repositoris -> Right click the branch -> check out as -> check out as ...New Project Wizard. ->  retype branch -> Makefile Project with Existing code ** (as a side note does anyone know how to specify the directory for the new project?)

Anyone who didn't do this and doesn't want to re-checkout can remove the project and re-add it using "new project"

At this point "Add to CVS ignore" was no longer greyed out. So you can now use that route if you want.

At this point however i tried something else i hadnt used before **Team->synchronize with repo**. This Seemed to bring up only the **Changes** i had made and therefore did not have any of the "new files" which was all the files i didn't want to commit. I was therefore able to simply double check the folders and then do a blanket commit on all those files in the sync view. It is really important to note that I actually had some build generated .h and .c files, so if i had succeeded in ignoring certain files, i would have still checked in these unwanted files (silver lining i suppose).

Perhaps i should rephrase the question to "large commit" to be more helpful to future cvs + eclipse newbies? anyone agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `.cvsignore` file on a per-directory basis containing the files in the directory that you want cvs to ignore. Note that if you want this to persist, you will have to commit that file too. @khmarbaise pointed to some documentation that talks about what kind of thing you can put in this file.

If you want to ignore certain file types on a global basis, then you should check out the `CVSROOT` module and make additions to the `cvsignore` file in that module (note that lack of a "dot" at the start of the name). Don't forget to commit this change for it to take effect.

Both `.cvsignore` and `cvsignore` files can contain the same types of information.

Comment: As mentioned in the update i always assumed CVSROOT was the "CVS" folder located in the top most directory, it includes other files like "Tag", "Root" etc. is this wrong?

Comment: @chrispepper1989 No. `CVSROOT` is a module in your CVS repository. It contains various administrative files for the repository.

Comment: Ohh! massive thanks for clearing that up, 'Im very new to CVS and have never created a repository myself. I feel quite stupid now, hmm its a shame that i wont...and probably shouldn't have permission to that folder.


So is it possible to create a new folder similar to CVSROOT lower down the tree that would then do it globally for that branch / folder?


Or is it a all or nothing type affair? and i will just have to add .cvsignore to each folder? i suppose i could write a quick tool to add a .cvsignore in each directory...

Comment: "Out of the box", if you permission to check out a CVS module, then you can also check out the CVSROOT module. If you don't feel comfortable committing changes there, ask someone else such as the person who is in charge of teh repository.

Comment: Thanks Burhan Ali but is I would rather only apply this change further down the tree. Basically its like every department in the company uses this same CVS repo, with each branch/project being a different department/project. I've not explained that very well really but basically I wouldn't want to make the change to CVS root because as great as it would be for my project it could be disastrous for hundreds of other projects in the same repo.

Comment: OK. That makes perfect sense. Individual `.cvsignore` files are definitely the option for you then.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file which is call cvsignore which contains certan file types. I can't remember if it's called ".cvsignore" or "cvsignore". Check the [documentation](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/cvsignore.html).

Comment: It's both. One is per-directory, the other is global.